# Rescuing a virus from naked (c)DNA

Tags: biochemistry, virology

Reading the articles it seems that for several human virus strains, synthesizing the full-length genome then electroporating into vero cells and incubating a few days gave birth to living viruses that can infect people as well as the original do (thus offering an *easy* way to add some mutation and make chimeric virus)

Am I correct and what are the few facts to know about this ? For example influenza would need more efforts, transfecting either seven separated plasmids, or the full genome plus infecting with a living virus producing the influenza RNA polymerase.